# Push Notification from PHP to android phone using FCM (Android Studio)

Tags: php, android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I manage to send notification using Firebase Cloud Messenging (FCM) to android phone. The problem is that, when I click the notification on the status bar / notification area to open to new activity, the notification message text in the status bar is not carried foward to my new activity page. How to solve this problem. I want the text message "Success! This message is from PHP" can be seen in my new activity page (activiy_main.xml).

//example of php site

```
<?php 
  echo "Success! This message is from PHP";
?>
```

//activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="fcm.notification.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver class should look like this:

```
public class MyGcmPushReceiver extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = MyGcmPushReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from   SenderID of the sender.
     * @param bundle Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *               For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle bundle) {
        String title = bundle.getString("title");
        String message = bundle.getString("message");
        String image = bundle.getString("image");
        String timestamp = bundle.getString("created_at");
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.e(TAG, "Title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "image: " + image);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);

        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils();
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            //Here you set the message as an extra to the intent.
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(image)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, image);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
}
```